# Sitecore - Create File Download Link

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

In sitecore, I have items that have a "File" field.

When I use code such as the following:

```
var bioDoc = item["BiographyDocument"];
```

I get a string that looks like this:

```
<file mediaid=\"{3891941C-AC19-4DEB-AD5D-2E4FA4DD2E07}\" src=\"~/media/3891941CAC194DEBAD5D2E4FA4DD2E07.ashx\" />
```

How do I go from this string to a MediaItem and then a download link? I've spend quite a bit of time on this and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the MediaManager to get the MediaItem url:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField field =  
             (Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField)myItem.Fields["BiographyDocument"];
string url = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(field.MediaItem);
```

Comment: This worked for when I added the EnsurePrefix. StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(field.MediaItem))